# How extract rows from Pandas dataframe and add as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing assignment and have this problem.
I have dataframe with pandas datetime set as index and min and max temperatures for years 2004 through 2015.
Bellow example is shortened version. Actual data has ~160000 rows.

```
            |     id        |    data_c
------------|---------------|---------------
date        |               |
2005-01-01  | USW00004848   | -17.777778
2005-01-02  | USC00207320   | 65.555556
2005-01-03  | USC00207320   | -23.888889
2006-01-01  | USW00014833   | -42.222222
2006-01-02  | USW00014833   |  0.555556
2006-12-31  | USC00200032   | -11.666667
2007-12-29  | USC00205050   | -27.222222
2007-12-30  | USC00208202   | -17.777778
2007-12-31  | USC00201250   | -21.111111
2008-12-3   | USC00200230   | -27.222222
2008-01-4   | USW00004848   | -17.777778
2008-01-5   | USC00207320   | 65.555556
2009-01-01  | USC00207320   | -23.888889
2009-01-02  | USW00014833   | -42.222222
2009-01-03  | USW00014833   | 0.555556
2010-12-3   | USC00200032   | -11.666667
2010-12-4   | USC00205050   | -27.222222
2010-12-5   | USC00208202   | -17.777778
```

what I want to achieve is extract rows based on year and add according values in the same dataframe as columns.

```
        2005         2006         2007        2008         2009
                
0   -17.777778   -42.222222   -27.222222  -27.222222   -23.888889
1    65.555556    0.555556    -17.777778   -17.777778  -42.222222
2   -23.888889   -11.666667   -21.111111   65.555556   0.555556
```

I know I can filter values manually year by year(df.index.year==2005] and so on) and then add as columns, but I'm curious if there is more easier way to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the dtype of `df.index`?

Comment: pandas datetime

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming your original DataFrame is named 'df'
# Make sure your index is set to a pandas datetime index
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# Extract the year from the datetime index and create a new column for it
df['year'] = df.index.year

# Use pivot_table to reshape the data and create new columns for each year
pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index=df.index.dayofyear, columns='year', values='data_c', aggfunc='sum')

# Display the resulting DataFrame
print(pivot_df)
```